# Creating a webapp using JavaFX - is it possible?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm making a database for my project (wirtual clinic) which will be a web application, but here is a thing.. I want in order that my app will based on a JavaFX (MVC pattern, where in View segment I could use .fxml files edited in SceneBuilder) is this solution possible?

Comment: I would understand a "web application" to mean an application in which the user interface is one or more web pages (i.e. the UI is presented by a web browser). JavaFX is a toolkit for developing thick client (stand alone) UI interfaces. If you mean something different by "web application", can you specify what you mean? If not, I'm not clear what your question is.

Comment: I mean all visual stuff in this web application (GUI) could be create in FXML, I used FXML for creating my desktop applications (with SceneBuilder), but I was wondering is it possible that I could create GUI by FXML in web application? I don't know how I can explain it in the other way

Comment: Specify a UI in FXML to be displayed in a web browser? Basically, no. You can try to create a JavaFX application and [deploy it as an applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deploy_quick_start.html#A1334040), but making it work with browser security restrictions is prohibitively difficult imho.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a web application running in a browser with a backend in a container, then you cannot use JavaFX. But you might try [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com). There you can use either Java code or HTML to build your application. They also sell a [designer application](https://vaadin.com/designer).

Answer (score 2):

The http://javafx-samples.com/ mentioned in the other answer shows a JavaFX application running as a server process and mirrored thru the network using JavaScript. This is technically admirable and might work reasonably well for your use case but you should keep that in mind when comparing it to client side JavaScript solutions.

It will not work well for flaky internet connections and extending it will have limits since it would require both Java server side code and JavaScript side code.

Such architectures have been used extensively in the past (e.g. Echo2, AjaxSwing etc.) and they all never gained serious traction even when compared to similar architectures such as GWT.

There are now several client side JavaScript based VM's including [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/) which are pretty amazing and can produce pretty good results entirely on the client e.g. we used this VM in a [recent demo](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ratatouilles-restaurant-in-code.html).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, but with the plugin and updates problems.

Some solutions are in progress. You can check this site:
http://javafx-samples.com/

It is promising I think because you don't need plugin.